# How can I export my spotipy code efficiently?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, spotipy

I wrote a python program using the spotipy library. I used pyinstaller to create executables and it works fine for me. However, when I try to email it to someone (via gmail, sent through imessage) it doesn't run correctly. We are all on Mac OS X. When they try to open it with terminal, it opens terminal but the program doesn't run. I created the executable with the following command:

```
pyinstall -F example.py
```

and I sent the executable in the dist folder. I've never really tried to distribute any code before so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For XOS and if you gonna use pyinstaller:

[pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Put this line at the top of your python code and it will inform your operating systems to look up the binary program which needs for the execution of the python script for example it is the python interpreter.

Therefore it depends on your operating system where it keeps the python interpreter. If you have Ubuntu as operating system it keeps the python interpreter in **/usr/bin/python** so you have to write this line at the starting of your python script;

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

1. Write above line at the top of your python code
2. Saving your code
3. Start your command terminal
4. Make sure the script lies in your present working directory
5. Type chmod +x script_name.py
6. Now you can start the script by clicking the script. An alert box will appear; press "Run" or "Run in Terminal" in the alert box;
7. Or, at the terminal prompt, type ./script_name.py

For Windows as your OS.

1. Make sure the python script contains:

   `if __name__ == '__main__': 
        main()`
2. Make sure you do not have a folder with the same name as the script you are trying to turn into an executable.
3. Make sure you do not have any .ipynb in the same folder where you will create your executable, it will not run properly.
4. You can follow these instructions:
   [Making Executable Python](https://github.com/jorgeavilacartes/making-my-own-executable-python)

Comment: The link you sent is for windows. Is there a way to do this from OSX and not windows?

Comment: @Kev I changed my answer and I hope it helps, otherwise please do not hesitate to issue your question again.